# Need help translating a formal definition into FOL

Tags: definitions, symbolic-logic, formalisation, translation

I need help formally translating the following definition into FOL: "a property F is essential to an object x if and only if x could not have been the object it is without possessing the property F."

So far I have "F is an essential property of x iffdef ∃x(¬F(x) → x ≠ x)"

Would that be correct?

Comment: This is a strange sentence to formalise in FOL. It talks about ‘essential’ and ‘could’, both concepts which are more naturally captured in modal logic. It also quantifies over properties – ‘a property’ really means ‘for all properties’ here – and that’s something you can only do in Second-Order Logic. (You can’t formalise ‘F is an essential property’ since you don’t have predicates to apply to F.) You’ll probably need to say something like: For all x, if x is a property, then… - so, have a FO predicate saying ‘…is a property’.

Comment: @MarkOxford - correct; we need properties of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need two ingredients : high-order logic, because we have a property of properties.

And, IMO, we need modalities, in order to express the necessary "connection" involved in the concept of *essence*.

Compare with [Gödel's ontological proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof#Symbolic_notation).

I would suggest :

> **Ess(F,x) ↔ ( F(x) & □∀y (~Fy → y ≠ x))**.